Find the duplicate records with combination of two column
I have table (Project_Supplier_Status) in MySQL like below:



Project
supplier
Status
Track_Id




Pro1
Sup1
P
1


Pro1
Sup1
P
2


Pro1
Sup1
P
3


Pro1
Sup1
P
4


Pro5
Sup5
P
5


Pro5
Sup5
P
6


Pro5
Sup6
P
7



Problem statement:

If all duplicate Pro1 (project) have same Sup1 (supplier), then we
have to keep one record of them as status P and discard the other
records as status F.
If all duplicate Pro5 (project) have multiple supplier (Sup5, Sup6), then we
have to discard all the records as status F.

I need the Mysql query to execute above 2 operations on 100 000 records.
UPDATE
The desired output:



Project
supplier
Status
Track_Id




Pro1
Sup1
P
1


Pro1
Sup1
F
2


Pro1
Sup1
F
3


Pro1
Sup1
F
4


Pro5
Sup5
F
5


Pro5
Sup5
F
6


Pro5
Sup6
F
7




Do the records really have no unique key?

Please add the desired result to your question. And what happens if further suppliers appear, how to deal with them? Your question is very vague.

There are rows which are complete duplicates. Such records are indistinguishable in MySQL. If there is no any expression which is unique in the table (PK candidate) then the only solution is iterative (one row in a group per one iteration) UPDATE in stored procedure.

@Turo : There is unique column in table TRACK_ID, see the updates.

@JonasMetzler : I have updated the desired output.

@Akina : There is a column Track_id which have unique numbers.

Show us your attempt (query/queries). As to me, you need simple update statement.

Common multiple-table UPDATE.
UPDATE Project_Supplier_Status t1
JOIN Project_Supplier_Status t2 USING (Project)
SET t1.Status = 'F' -- update status
WHERE (t1.supplier <> t2.supplier) -- if exists another supplier
   OR (t1.supplier = t2.supplier AND t1.Track_Id > t2.Track_Id) -- or lower id
   ;

fiddle

Query is not working, its throwing the Syntax error: unexpected 'JOIN'.

@AniruddhParihar You do something wrongly. The query is synthactically correct. Check your code carefully. PS. Fiddle added - ensure.

I am really sorry for that, It was my mistake. I copied some ASCI with the query from somewhere, I have written the query in notepad, And its working like charm. Thanks Again Akina.

Does this query will work on snowFlake DB?

@AniruddhParihar I don't know - simply try.
